# Evaluation of definite Integral Involving fractional part and floor part of $x$

Tags: integration

> Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{n^2+n+1}{\left\{\frac{y}{2}\right\}}e^{\{\frac{y}{2}\}}d\left(\{y\}\right) = \;,$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$
>
> and $y=\{y\}+\lfloor y \rfloor$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$I = \int_{0}^{n(n+1)}{\left\{\frac{y}{2}\right\}}e^{\{\frac{y}{2}\}}d\left(\{y\}\right)+\int_{n^2+n}^{n^2+n+1}{\left\{\frac{y}{2}\right\}}e^{\{\frac{y}{2}\}}d\left(\{y\}\right)$$

Here $0<\underbrace{n(n+1)}_{\bf{even \; natural\; no.}}<n^2+n+1$

Now how can i solve after that, Help required, Thanks

Comment: Often if one writes $\displaystyle \int_A^B \cdots\cdots\,dw$, it means the variable $w$ goes from $A$ to $B$.  But $\{y\}$ cannot go from $0$ to $n^2+n+1$, but only from $0$ to $1$, repeatedly, as $y$ goes from $0$ to $n^2+n+1$. So it looks as if you MIGHT have intended this to be a Riemann–Stieltjes integral. If so, then each jump discontinuity of $y\mapsto\{y\}$ would contribute something depending on the size of the jump. But in a Riemann–Stieltjes integral $\displaystyle\int_A^B f(x)\,dg(x)$, the functions $f$ and $g$ can't have any points of discontinuity in common. $\text{So }\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots\,$some uncertainty remains about the meaning of this question. $\qquad$